# Applescript to forward mail with attachments?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create an applescript that will take messages that match a certain filter YYYY), and forward them to a specific notebook in Evernote (XXXX), with the attachment intact. So far, I've gotten this script to handle the forwarding to a Evernote notebook thing, but I can't seem to get it to deal with attachments correctly.

How do I attach all of the attachments in the emails found by the filter (which would ideally run when messages are received) to the new forwarded email?

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages selection for rule YYYY
        tell application "Mail"
            set theSelection to selection
            set thesubject to subject of item 1 of theSelection
            set theAttachments to every attachment of content of theSelection
            set theForwardedMessage to forward (item 1 of theSelection) with opening window

            tell theForwardedMessage
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"ZZZZ"}

                set subject to subject of item 1 of theSelection & " @XXXX"
                repeat with a from 1 to length of theAttachments
                    log "message_attachment =" & a
                    make new attacment with properties {filename:a} at after last paragraph
                end repeat
                send
            end tell
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: Can I ask why you do not just use the normal Mail.app rules to forward the message. Not used it but I assume it forwards the attachments with the email.

Comment: Also  I have had some requests for this on my blog. And I have found if you want the attachments from one email for a new draft. They have to be saved some where first. A quote from my blog. "In your script it is not possible to get the paths of the attachments. Which are needed for the ” {file name:theAttachment} ” part of the script. Because the paths of the attachments in the original email do not exist in a way that we can get at. (not that I have found anyway)"

Comment: I'm not using the normal mail forward rules because I want to be able to change the subject of the message in order to file to an evernote notebook (via @notebook in the subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dug out the script I wrote a little while ago for someone.

It works on the selected emails in Mail.app, saves the attachments in the user temp folder.
then adds them to you new email. As I said you could not AFAIK just pull the attachments out of the original email and into a new email.

It should not be that hard for you to convert this back to a mail rule.

There will be the obvious things for you to change in the script anyway. Like you will want it to send rather than open and display the new email. and body, subject etc..

```
    #copyright Mark Hunte 2013
--using terms from application "Mail"
--on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule


-- set up the attachment folder path

set folderName to "temp"
set homePath to (path to temporary items from user domain) as text

set attachmentsFolder to (homePath & folderName) as text


tell application "Mail"
    set theMessages to (get selection)
    repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
        delay 0.5

        -- set up the folder name for this mail message's attachments. We use the time stamp of the  date received time stamp

        set timeStamp to (do shell script "date +%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S")

        set attachCount to count of (mail attachments of eachMessage)
        if attachCount is not equal to 0 then
            -- use the unix /bin/test command to test if the timeStamp folder  exists. if not then create it and any intermediate directories as required
            if (do shell script "/bin/test -e " & quoted form of ((POSIX path of attachmentsFolder) & "/" & timeStamp) & " ; echo $?") is "1" then
                -- 1 is false
                do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of ((POSIX path of attachmentsFolder) & "/" & timeStamp)

            end if
            set attachList to {}
            try
                -- Save the attachment

                #SET replaceBadCharsWithUnderscoreInFileNames  TO TRUE  IF YOU WANT BAD CHARACTERS REMOVED FROM THE FILE NAMES THAT MAY STOP THE FILES SAVING DOWN
                set replaceBadCharsWithUnderscoreInFileNames to true
                ####

                repeat with theAttachment in eachMessage's mail attachments
                    if replaceBadCharsWithUnderscoreInFileNames then
                        set originalName to my replaceBadChars((name of theAttachment as string))

                    else
                        set originalName to (name of theAttachment as string)

                    end if



                    set savePath to attachmentsFolder & ":" & timeStamp & ":" & originalName
                    try
                        save theAttachment in file (savePath)
                        copy (savePath) to end of attachList
                    end try
                end repeat

                --on error msg
                --display dialog msg
            end try
            set theSubject to "forwarded email"
            set theBody to " body of email "
            set theAddress to "youeEmail@me.com"


            set visable to true

            set theForwardedMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return}
            tell theForwardedMessage
                set visible to true
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress} without quote original message

                tell content
                    repeat with i from 1 to the count of attachList
                        set this_file to (item i of attachList as alias)

                        make new attachment with properties {file name:this_file} at after the last paragraph
                    end repeat

                end tell

            end tell



        end if
        delay 0.5
    end repeat

end tell
--end perform mail action with messages
--end using terms from
on replaceBadChars(TEXT_)
    --log TEXT_
    set OkChars to {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "_", ".", "(", ")", "-", ",", space}
    set TEXT_ to characters of TEXT_
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in TEXT_
        set this_char to item i of TEXT_
        if this_char is not in OkChars then
            set item i of TEXT_ to "_"
        else

        end if
    end repeat
    set TEXT_ to TEXT_ as string

    do shell script " echo " & quoted form of TEXT_
end replaceBadChars
```